# Grails 3 fontawesome setup

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

i'm attempting to include fontawesome (fa) in my grails 3 project. I saw for grails2 there was a plugin for this, but the configuration and explanation for how to install this plugin didn't seem to work in grails 3.

So I tried to add fa more or less manually by creating an assets/fonts/ directory, and placing the fonts in there, added the css to my stylesheets directory and referenced it from the application.css. When I run in Idea via grails run-app all the fa resources show up fine.

However when I package a war file to run in tomcat, none of the fa resources show up at all. When I look at the compiled style sheet that is created for the app, the ../fonts/ that I put in my fa style sheet has been removed, and then the font files can't be found.

```
@font-face {font-family: 'FontAwesome';src: url('fontawesome-webfont-32400f4e08932a94d8bfd2422702c446.eot?v=4.5.0')
```

This generated font resource, and all the others are not resolvable(404) from the root of my application, but are resolvable if I prepend /assets/ to them.

What am I missing configuration wise with the asset pipeline to get this working?

Comment: did you check bootstrap-framework plugin for grails3? seems fa is included there

Comment: thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: FYI the bootstrap plugins for grails 3 are all out of date/unmaintained.  strangely, bootstrap (and old version) seems to be included by default in grails 3.3.0 (not sure if it was in there before this).  However, including fontawesome is a manual, non trivial process sadly.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you can use the Grails 3 bootstrap-framework hosted on GitHub https://github.com/kensiprell/bootstrap-framework

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder called 'fonts' in grails-app/assets. In this folder place the unzipped content containing font-awesome files. You should have something like:

```
grails-app
|__assets
   |__fonts
      |__css
      |__fonts
      |__less
      |__scss
   ....
```

Then, for the asset pipeline to know the new directory, reference it in the build.gradle file. You should have something like:

```
assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
    includes = ["fonts/*"]
}
```

Comment: I have followed your steps to put the fontawesome files under assets, and have edited the build.gradle.  How do I now include the fonts in the app? how do I link  to them so I can use them?

Answer (score 0):

Download Fonts from this link [enter link description here](http://fontawesome.io/) and in that add Fonts folder only to assets in grail app.Add below code:

```
assets {
minifyJs = true
minifyCss = true
includes = ["fonts/*"]
```

}